# Create different DAGs based on output from task in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Say I have three functions:

```py
f1 = get_data(query):
       df = pandas.read_sql(query)
       return df

f2 = change_data(df):
      df["mean"] = df["col1"].mean()
      return df

f3 = push_new_data(data_base):
      #push some new data to the database
      return 0
```

I need one DAG if the datafra from `f1` is empty, and another one if it is not. If we name our task for `f1` as `t1`, `f2` as `t2` and `f3` as `t3` then the DAG-pesudo-code would look something like

```py
df = t1(query)
if df.shape[0]>0: #some data
    t1>>t2
else:
   t1>>t3
```

but I doubt this is the right way to do so

Comment: I don't really understand what you are doing here. PythonOperator functions should not return df. It seems like your code is native python and you try to force Airflow over it rather than refactor it to be used with Airflow. In any case you can use `TriggerDagRunOperator` to invoke any DAG you'd need.

Comment: I have editted it - the last snippet is more like some pseudo-code to explain what I want. If I could write such that it worked, then I wouldnt need to post the question ;-)

Comment: The problem is that it's not clear if your issue is with finding the proper way to set dependencies so your workflow will run/skip the proper tasks according to your logic or is it about passing information between the tasks. The concept of get the data in one function and transform it in another is not Airflowy because you can not share data between tasks (you can share some metadata like status, short string etc.. but not df)

Comment: to be more clear. The code as you posted (in my opinion) should be in 1 PythonOperator with 1 python callable.